# how can i remove ng repeat data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two table and i want to append second table data in $scope.notiData and how can i remove ng repeat data if i click remove symbol X. I have some code but it is not working.please help anyone

http://jsfiddle.net/A6bt3/118/

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
function checkBoxCtrl($scope) {
$scope.tableOne = [{
        firstname: 'robert',
        value: 'a'
    }, {
        firstname: 'raman',
        value: 'b'
    }, {
        firstname: 'kavi',
        value: 'c'
    }, {
        firstname: 'rorank',
        value: 'd'
    }
];
$scope.tableTwo = [];//the table to be submitted
function removeitems(tableRef) { //revmove items from tableRef
    var i;
    for (i = tableRef.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        if (tableRef[i].checked) {
            tableRef.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
$scope.btnRight = function () {
   //Loop through tableone
    $scope.tableOne.forEach(function (item, i) {
       // if item is checked add to tabletwo
        if (item.checked) {
            $scope.tableTwo.push(item);
        }
    })
    removeitems($scope.tableOne);
}
$scope.btnAllRight = function () {
    $scope.tableOne.forEach(function (item, i) {
        item.checked = true;
        $scope.tableTwo.push(item);
    })
    removeitems($scope.tableOne);
}
$scope.btnLeft = function () {
    $scope.tableTwo.forEach(function (item, i) {
        if (item.checked) {
            $scope.tableOne.push(item);
        }
    })
    removeitems($scope.tableTwo);
}
$scope.btnAllLeft = function () {
    $scope.tableTwo.forEach(function (item, i) {
        item.checked = true;
        $scope.tableOne.push(item);
    })
    removeitems($scope.tableTwo);
}
$scope.done = function () {
    //alert(angular.toJson($scope.tableTwo));
        $scope.notiData = $scope.tableTwo;  
}
    $scope.removeRow = function () {

}

};
```

Comment: there is no X symbol in your fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it like that :

```
$scope.removeRow = function (item) {
  var index = $scope.notiData.indexOf(item);
  $scope.notiData.splice(index, 1); 
}
```

and to merge the arrays:

```
$scope.done = function () {
    angular.extend($scope.notiData, $scope.tableTwo);
}
```

dont forget to initialize notiData :

```
$scope.notiData = [];
```

to resolve the problem of redirecting remove the `target="_blank"` and change `href`:

```
<a ng-repeat="data in notiData" class="emailButton" href="#">{{data.firstname}}<div class="" ng-click="removeRow()">X</div></a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A6bt3/122/

Comment: if i click X btn second table data also removing that is wrong..pls correct it

Comment: one more thing...before that i want to append second table data in  $scope.notiData like that $scope.notiData = $scope.notiData .concat($scope.tableTwo);  but it is not working. pls edit my fiddle

Comment: check the new solution

Comment: after i click that remove my page is redirected..how to resolve this issue?

Comment: append is not working: $scope.done = function(){ 
     $rootScope.notiData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.tableTwo));  
        angular.extend($rootScope.notiData, $scope.tableTwo);
     $tuxModalInstance.close();

    };

Answer (score 0):

html element

```
<a ng-repeat="data in notiData" class="emailButton">{{data.firstname}}
  <div class="" ng-click="removeRow($index)">X</div>
</a>
```

remove function

```
$scope.removeRow = function (index) {
        $scope.notiData.splice(index,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pass the index of the data element in the removeRow() function from the view.

```
<a ng-repeat="data in notiData" class="emailButton" href="#">{{data.firstname}}
  <div class="" ng-click="removeRow($index)">X</div>
</a>
```

and in controller filter the passed index element from the list.

```
$scope.removeRow = function (index) {

     $scope.notiData = $scope.notiData.filter(function(elem){      
               return elem !== $scope.notiData[index]
        })
 }
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/w5upkawt/